# How to update existing table JHipster sample app?

Tags: maven, liquibase, jhipster

I have created an entity called "**event**" using command **yo jhipster:entity event** while creating I forgot add one column let's say "**event_title**" so, I have added this(event_tile) column manually in liquibase changelog xml. Now how to update **event** table with newly added column?

Answer (score 7):

You need to include the new changelog file in your `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml` file.

```
<include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/my_new_changelog.xml" 
    relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

Next time you run the app, changes will be applied.

You can also update the database with the following maven task :
`mvn liquibase:update`.

Here is the [doc about using jhipster in development](http://jhipster.github.io/development.html).

Comment: i'm getting follwing exception if try to execute mvn liquibase:update Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:update (default-cli) on project ubweb: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Set your database infos in `pom.xml` file. It's specified in plugin tag for `liquibase-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 3):

I created a file on

```
src/main/resources/config/liquibase
```

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

<changeSet author="lazaro" id="altertable-02">
    <addColumn catalogName="mySchema"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="myTableName">
        <column name="atributeName" type="bigint"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

And added on

```
src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
```

A include tag:

```
<include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/add_column_quantity_entity_Item.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```