# How to add a new field to a domain in Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

The general case: Let's say you have an entity Appuser with a field streetaddress and you create the jhipster app. It works, database is created, but you realize that you also need the postalcode. So you modified all the pieces you need, but the field is not created in your database. How am I missing?

Actually, I added a new relationship to an existing entity and I did modified:

```
    modified:   src/main/java/com/spingular/web/domain/Blog.java
    modified:   src/main/java/com/spingular/web/service/BlogQueryService.java
    modified:   src/main/java/com/spingular/web/service/dto/BlogCriteria.java
    modified:   src/main/java/com/spingular/web/service/dto/BlogDTO.java
    modified:   src/main/java/com/spingular/web/service/mapper/BlogMapper.java
    modified:   src/main/java/com/spingular/web/web/rest/BlogResource.java
    modified:   src/main/resources/.h2.server.properties
```

I drop the database and create a new one but the new relationship is not there. What am I missing here?

If you have any documentation, great. Thanks.

Comment: You might need to manually update the liquibase files. Those are what build the DB

Comment: do you know how or where can I find some documentaion about that? Thanks

Comment: see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004755/how-to-update-existing-table-jhipster-sample-app

Comment: Have you read the doc? https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates-with-the-entity-sub-generator

Comment: Yes, thanks. It worked.